# cannot convert Java.IO.FileOutputStream to System.IO.Stream?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to save the picture and in the line *bitmapImg.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, fos);* displays an error **cannot convert Java.IO.FileOutputStream to System.IO.Stream**. How to solve it?

```
File file = new File(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures + File.Separator + "newProdict.png");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try
            {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                if (fos != null)
                {
                    bitmapImg.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, fos);
                    fos.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: Bitmap is an image which I'm trying to save to the gallery of the smartphone. C#

Comment: I believe you should use FileStream instead of FileOutputStream

Comment: edited the path in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compress function expects something derived from the .net System.IO.Stream while you passing a class from the java namespace, use the FileStream instead:

```
    try
    {

     string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath, "newProdict.png");
     var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        if (fs != null)
        {
            bitmapImg.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 90, fs);
            fos.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: Could not find a part of the path "/Pictures/newProdict.png"

Comment: Great. If you can help with answers to this question?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584067/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-internal-memory-of-the-smartphone-and-the-dcim-folder)

Comment: @ХЫтрыйツ try `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`