# How to get the path to the internal memory of the smartphone and the DCIM folder?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to get the path to the internal memory of the smartphone and the DCIM folder, then to save the photo there?

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
FileStream file = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "newProdict_" + product.Width + "x" + product.Height + ".png"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the DCIM folder like that:

```
var dcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(System.Environment.DirectoryDcim).Path;
```

For writing files you can use the nuget package [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) so you already have everything in a cross platform manner:

```
var folder = await FileSystem.Current.GetFolderFromPathAsync(dcimFolder);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
using (System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim); error is cannot convert string to System.Environment.SpecialFolder

Comment: It needs to be Android.OS.Environment:
string path = Android.OS.Environment.GetFolderPath(Android.OS.Environment.Dire‌​ctoryDcim);

Comment: "Environment" does not contain a definition for "GetFolderPath"

Comment: You're absolutely right, I messed that up. But I fixed it in the answer now.

Comment: `var dcimFolder = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(System.Environment.DirectoryDcim).Path;` 

And again you are not right.)) Because I need the internal memory and not the external.

Comment: The name of the method is just misleading, it will return the path to the internal memory DCIM folder. Give it a try!

Comment: at the time of creation displays "Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/newProdict.png" is denied"

Comment: Have you declared all necessary permissions in the app manifest?

Comment: Thank you. Works, but after testing it still saves to the SD card

Comment: The term "internal" in this context is used in terms of "internal for your app", so the storage that can only be accessed through your app. Everything else is called external. That's why I said it is misleading. In most cases the code above will return the path to the DCIM folder on the phone, but sometimes it might return the path to the DCIM folder on the sd card, this behaviour depends on the manufacturer.